# Dynamically hide or show legend in highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

In my application i am using highchart, I want to know how to hide or show the legend in highchart

I have tried this :

```
var options = {
            chart: {
                type: 'column',
            },
            title: {
                text: 'my chart',
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    fontSize: '26px',
                    color: '#000000'
                }         
            },
            xAxis: {
                ..........Some code.....
            },
            yAxis: {
                ..........Some code.....
            },
            legend : { },
            series :[{.........Some code.....}]
 }

 var legend = { align: 'right',
        x: -70,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 20,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        borderColor: '#CCC',
        borderWidth: 1,
        shadow: false
 };
 if(isShow){
    options.legend.push=legend;
 }
 $('#MYCHART').highcharts(options);
```

I have tried this but i am not getting when isShow is true, I mean that legend is not adding dynamically.

I want to show the legend based on my isShow value.

Comment: where is your isShow value created? Check that is is indeed a boolean value and not a string or something else. print the value before if

Comment: I have dynamically getting the isShow value, its boolean

Comment: so what is the problem? Your isShow value is always correct, just the legend not adding? If that's so you ll have to give us more code to show. Are you "pushing" legend there like an array? its push() and not push = , and also you can't push to an object?

Comment: I knwo this is wrong, that why i came here. how to dynamically hide or show legend

Comment: Similar topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17857680/highcharts-hide-and-show-legend/17857930#17857930

Comment: That is happening at the time of action, but i want to do that at the time of showing chart itself

Comment: So when you load chart legend should be or not be printed?

Comment: when chat is load based on my isShow value legend should be or not

Comment: So where is the problem? I introduce you example which show/hide, only what you need is replace click button action with your condition, which check isShow flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the enabled property of legend i have achieved that i want

In JavaScript

```
if(!isShowAns){
    options.legend["enabled"]=false;
}
```

Its working well

Answer (score 0):

because attribute enabled = false so legend not show
You can read more document here
http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#legend

```
enabled: Boolean
Enable or disable the legend. Defaults to false.
```

You should enable it by set attribute `enabled: true`